# Python write_i2c_block_data Potentiometer

Tags: python-3.x, i2c

I had written some code for the Arduino which controls the DS1844 Quad Digital Potentiometer a while back. I'm now on myt 2nd day of Python and stuct coverting this:

```
const int address = 0x28;  // This is the address of the DS1844 

void DS1844(int pot, int value) {    // pots 0 - 3 (4 of), value 0 - 63 

  // prevents values that are too large from overwriting address bits
  value = (value > 63) ? 63 : value;

  // prevents mistransmission of address bits
  pot = (pot > 3) ? 3 : pot;

  byte bvalue = byte(value);
  byte bpot = byte(pot);

  bpot = bpot << 6;
  byte SendWriteVal = bpot + bvalue;

  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  Wire.write(SendWriteVal);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

into Python - I have so far:

```
from smbus import SMBus
import time


addr = 0x28 # bus address

bus = SMBus(1)

time.sleep(1)

value = 35
pot = 0

bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, pot, [6, value])
```

Which I'm thinking it's very wrong. Please can anyone help?

Comment: What errors you are experience? What problems have been occurred so far?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I've not long managed to get it working: with:  
    def DS1844(self, pot, value):
        bpot = pot << 6
        bus.write_byte_data(addr, bpot, bpot + value)
        time.sleep(0.1)